# Error: Expected content key de1e4a02ec63c4eb to exist getting this error in React. I am using parcel as a bundler

Tags: reactjs, node.js, build, parceljs, parcel

While creating a react app from scratch (without using create-react-app) using parcel bundler, the parcel throws the following error:

```
  Error: Expected content key de1e4a02ec63c4eb to exist
      at nullthrows (F:\react\node_modules\nullthrows\nullthrows.js:7:15)
      at AssetGraph.getNodeIdByContentKey (F:\react\node_modules\@parcel\graph\lib\ContentGraph.js:67:38)
      at F:\react\node_modules\@parcel\core\lib\SymbolPropagation.js:52:82
      at Array.map (<anonymous>)
      at propagateSymbols (F:\react\node_modules\@parcel\core\lib\SymbolPropagation.js:52:61)
      at AssetGraphBuilder.build (F:\react\node_modules\@parcel\core\lib\requests\AssetGraphRequest.js:168:62)
      at async Object.run (F:\react\node_modules\@parcel\core\lib\requests\AssetGraphRequest.js:60:37)
      at async RequestTracker.runRequest (F:\react\node_modules\@parcel\core\lib\RequestTracker.js:633:20)
      at async Object.run (F:\react\node_modules\@parcel\core\lib\requests\BundleGraphRequest.js:103:11)
      at async RequestTracker.runRequest (F:\react\node_modules\@parcel\core\lib\RequestTracker.js:633:20)
```

How can I solve this?

The version of parcel is 2.9.3

I have tried deleting cache and also tried recreating the whole project but nothing happened.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 28):

If you are using parcel then try to delete `.parcel-cache` folder and then Rerun the build.

Answer (score 6):

Deleting `.parcel-cache` folder works fine.

Instead of every time deleting it manually, you can simply add `rm -rf .parcel-cache &&` before your `start`, `dev` or `build` command in  *`package.json`*.

##### `package.json`

```
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "rm -rf .parcel-cache && parcel",
    "build": "rm -rf .parcel-cache && parcel build"
  }
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Remove-Item -Recurse -Force .parcel-cache
```

when you run Remove-Item -Recurse -Force .parcel-cache, it will forcefully and recursively delete the .parcel-cache directory and all its contents. **Use this command carefully**, as it permanently removes the specified directory and its content.
**then run** `npx parcel <entry point(like index.html)>`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `npm cache clean &&` before `npm Start` and `npm run build`, this command is used to clear the Parcel cache.

Answer (score 1):

Add below in your package.json.

```
"scripts": 
{
    "start": "rm -rf .parcel-cache && parcel",
    "build": "rm -rf .parcel-cache && parcel build"
}
```

Then run `npm cache clean --force` and then finally you can run your script using `npx parcel filename.html`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using parcel then try to delete ".parcel-cache" folder. And then Rerun the build.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly cancel the build (ctrl + c).
Then delete "parcel-cache.
then return the build (in terminal :- npx parcel index.html).
then,
if you import like this - import {ReactDOM} from 'react-dom'
replace it with code below :-
import ReactDOM from "react-dom"